# Mixed effects/nested model giving different EMS tables in R and Minitab, and I believe Minitab is incorrect. Anyone know why it would be wrong?

Tags: r, mixed-model, nested-models, minitab

I have a dataset at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PB_S7oX2Tqgz_BEUUcHfLOww0cNJ-IgN6B34UTequlw/edit?usp=sharing that shows a mixed model where Machine and Station are fixed effects and Power is a random effect. Power is also nested within Machine.

I have run this in R using gad and it produced some results I expected when I calculated by hand:

```
machines$machine_f <- as.fixed(machines$Machine)
machines$station_f <- as.fixed(machines$Station)
machines$power_r <- as.random(machines$Powre)
mod <- aov(Value^2~power_r%in%machine_f+machine_f*station_f+power_r%in%machine_f*station_f, machines)
gad(mod)

OUTPUT
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Value^2
                            Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
machine_f                    2   77867   38933   0.0392  0.962068    
station_f                    2   62646   31323   1.6142  0.274835    
power_r:machine_f            3 2981661  993887 183.8735 < 2.2e-16 ***
machine_f:station_f          4   63673   15918   0.8203  0.556701    
power_r:machine_f:station_f  6  116427   19405   3.5899  0.006841 ** 
Residual                    36  194590    5405                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


#generate the EMS table
estimates(mod)

$mse
                            Mean square estimates                                    
machine_f                   "Res + power_r:machine_f + machine_f"                    
station_f                   "Res + power_r:machine_f:station_f + station_f"          
power_r:machine_f           "Res + power_r:machine_f"                                
machine_f:station_f         "Res + power_r:machine_f:station_f + machine_f:station_f"
power_r:machine_f:station_f "Res + power_r:machine_f:station_f"                      
Residual                    "Res"
```

And then I do it Minitab using Stat -> ANOVA -> General Linear Model -> Fit General Linear Model

Then, in the random/nested menu I put Power nested in Machine, and select Power as Random. I fit it using lambda=2 in the box-cox transformation to get y^2, and then it produces these results:

```
Analysis of Variance for Transformed Response

Source                    DF    Seq SS      Contribution    Adj SS     Adj MS   F-Value P-Value
Machine                    2    77867       2.23%           77867      38933    0.04    0.962
Power(Machine)             3    2981661     85.27%          2981661    993887   51.22   0.000
Station                    2    62646       1.79%           62646      31323    1.61    0.275
Machine*Station            4    63673       1.82%           63673      15918    0.82    0.557
Station*Power(Machine)     6    116427      3.33%           116427     19405    3.59    0.007
Error                     36    194590      5.56%           194590     5405      
Total                     53    3496863     100.00%
```

And for the EMS table:

```
Expected Mean Squares, using Adjusted SS
Source                         Expected Mean Square for Each Term
1   Machine                    (6) + 3.0000 (5) + 9.0000 (2) + Q[1, 4]
2   Power(Machine)             (6) + 3.0000 (5) + 9.0000 (2)
3   Station                    (6) + 3.0000 (5) + Q[3, 4]
4   Machine*Station            (6) + 3.0000 (5) + Q[4]
5   Station*Power(Machine)     (6) + 3.0000 (5)
6   Error                      (6)
```

Now, the only differences between these two tables is the factor of Power nested within Machine. This means that Minitab and R are consistently using a different denominator for multiple other effects, but Minitab seems to miscalculate the nested effect. I have done this multiple times in R and Minitab rearranging the factors in both to determine if the EMS was shifting due to that, but that was not the problem.

The EMS table provided by R matches up with the work I did by hand, so I am almost certain Minitab is incorrect here. I am also almost certain there is probably something in Minitab I can do to correct this. Does anyone know how I can work in Minitab to produce the correct EMS table with the correct F test? Or will I have to do this in R because this is a shortcoming for Minitab?

Comment: Non-obvious differences in mixed-model assumptions can make a difference in the denominator for some F-tests (arising from the way Expected Mean Squares are computed). // Maybe google 'restricted' vs. 'unrestricted' model. Often one of the two is the 'default' for a software program. (I seem to recall Minitab changed it's default a few years back.) // When such differences btw software programs persist it is because there is controversy as to which method is correct in which circumstances. // Maybe worth noting for your data that both programs find same 2 interaction effects to be significant.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why Minitab is giving you a different EMS than R is because it's either using a restricted mixed model or unrestricted mixed model. I'm not sure if R is using a restricted model or unrestricted model, but whatever it's using, Minitab is using the opposite. I'd say play around with Minitab and see if you can switch from restricted to unrestricted mixed model and see what you get...
-Amateur student in biostatistics